# Как использовать модуль на одном языке в программе на другом? (R & Python)

Tags: python, r

Хочу понять принцип, как скрипт написанный, например, на Python можно подтянуть в качестве библиотеки в другой язык, например, R.
Цель такого вопроса - использование преимуществ одного языка в общем проекте на другом.

Вопрос общий, в качестве ответа подойдут ссылки на ресурсы начального уровня.

Comment: Пакет `reticulate` в R.

Comment: Посмотрю, спасибо!
От Вас не спрятаться, шеф)